# What are the possible values for the length of side $f$

Tags: geometry

> Given the quadrilateral below  , 
>   What are the possible values for the length of side $f$?

[image]

My try follows

Using triangle inequality

BD belongs to  (1,7)  &

Ac belongs to (1,9)

Now , what should I do ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Assuming only the lengths of the sides are given, $f$ can vary between $0$ and $3 + 4 + 5 = 12$

Comment: I assume that the angles are arbitrary in the picture, and only the side lengths are relevant?

Comment: @dromastyx  But how can we Use triangle inequality to get the same result?

Comment: @Medo I don't see how you should use it here?

Answer (score 1):

In the biggest possible case $g,h,i$ all lie almost exactly on one line, letting $f$ approach $3+4+5$ arbitrarily closely, but never reach it. So $f < 12$.

Since $3, 4, 5$ can form a triangle, $f$ could be $0$. However since we're interested in a quadrilateral $f$ may not be zero, but can approach it to an arbitrarily small positive value. So $f > 0$.

Giving the result $0 < f < 12$.

Comment: Frankly, I think you're saying too much, considering how little the question says.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Perhaps, I always assume best intentions from askers, and not just people looking to get help for homework. Perhaps I'm a bit naive.

Comment: I didn't really have in mind that anything was wrong with the intentions of the poster, but rather that if you say a little bit, the poster might then ask questions that will make it clear where they are in their thinking process.

Comment: But how can  we Use  triangle inequality to get the same result?

Comment: @MichaelHardy When I help people interactively I am a huge proponent of the Socratic method, as it's terrific at making people understand their own blockades. In a fairly static format like stackexchange I have a hard time judging how much or little to say.

Answer (score 0):

A straight line is the shortest route between two points. If you straighten the part consisting of sides $g,$ $h,$ and $i,$ then $f$ is as long as it can get.

Comment: And I think perhaps you're saying a bit too little :) If one of the sides were $50$ your answer would be incomplete on the lower end.